# MySql - concat in query with left outer join

Tags: mysql, select, left-join, concatenation

I don't get it.  I've tried:

```
SELECT
table1.name, CONCAT( country,  '.', id ) AS table1.code,
table2.name
FROM tabel1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
table2 ON ( table1.code = table2.code )
```

I need to combine `country` and `id` to `country.id` because `table2.code` has this schema.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem? Are you getting null?

Comment: Did you notice that you typed `FROM tabel1` rather than `table2`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I understand you correct you might need something like this

```
SELECT t1.name t1_name,
       t2.name t2_name
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2 ON CONCAT(t1.country,  '.', t1.id ) = t2.code
```

**[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a75d7/5)**

Comment: Your Fiddle link goes to a blank fiddle.

Comment: @Sparky This fiddle was created more 1.5 years ago. It looks like SQLFiddle dropped old fiddles.

Comment: I realize that.  I just thought you'd like to know so you can update your answer to either remove or fix the fiddle.

Comment: This same method also works in Symfony using Doctrine.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone pulling his hair out because of the poor performance of `ON CONCAT()` joins: make sure you cast your non string values to `CHAR` it improves the performance astronomically:

```
SELECT t1.name t1_name,
       t2.name t2_name
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2 ON CONCAT(t1.country,  '.', CAST(t1.id AS CHAR) ) = t2.code
```

Explanation hides in MySQL docs for [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

> …If all arguments are non-binary strings, the result is a non-binary
>   string. If the arguments include any binary strings, the result is a
>   binary string. A numeric argument is converted to its equivalent
>   binary string form; if you want to avoid that, you can use an explicit
>   type **cast**…

*Credit for this goes to [Aurimas Mikalauskas](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/10/16/be-careful-when-joining-on-concat/).*

Comment: In case someone wants to set COLLATE:  `SELECT CAST('test' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) COLLATE utf8_bin`